# A field or property with the name was not found on the selected data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, datagrid

I am populating the following DataGrid with data from my SQL Database

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgUsers" BackColor="#F7F9FD" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
 OnItemCommand="dgItemCommand" runat="server" >
  <Columns>
     <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Username" DataField="Username" />
     <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" />
     <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="LastName" />
     <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Details">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Open" CommandName="OpenDetails"
                       CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Username")%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateColumn>
   </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

I am getting the information from two different tables in my database, FirstName and LastName come from one table and Username comes from a different table.

```
    cmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcedure", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", first);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", last);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(ds);

    dgUsers.DataSource = ds;
    dgUsers.DataBind();
```

I get the error that A field or property with the name 'FirstName' was not found on the selected data source. So it appears to get Username correctly but not FirstName or LastName. I have tripled checked that I have no typos, the fields in my table are indeed FirstName and LastName, as well as in my stored procedure which I show below. Does anyone see what I could be doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help!!

```
@Email varchar(MAX),
@FirstName varchar(20),
@LastName varchar(35)

AS

SELECT Username
From AgentLogin.dbo.AgentLogin
WHERE AgentNumID IN (SELECT AgentNumID FROM AgentLogin.dbo.AgentDetail WHERE
      ((CHARINDEX(@FirstName, FirstName) != 0) OR (CHARINDEX(@LastName, LastName) 
      != 0))) OR (CHARINDEX(@Email, Email) != 0)

SELECT FirstName, LastName
From AgentLogin.dbo.AgentDetail
WHERE AgentNumID IN (SELECT AgentNumID FROM AgentLogin.dbo.AgentLogin WHERE
      (CHARINDEX(@Email, Email) != 0)) OR ((CHARINDEX(@FirstName, FirstName) != 0) 
      OR (CHARINDEX(@LastName, LastName) != 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use an inner join.

SELECT    AgentLogin.Username, AgentDetail.FirstName, AgentDetail.LastName
FROM      Orders INNER JOIN
          AgentLogin ON AgentDetail.AgentNumID = AgentLogin.AgentNumID

Before you try to create a stored procedure try calling the Select in a function from code behind.

```
protected DataTable getTable()
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
StringBuilder cmdText = new StringBuilder();
cmdText.Append("SELECT AgentLogin.Username, AgentDetail.FirstName,    AgentDetail.LastName");
        cmdText.Append("FROM Orders INNER JOIN");
        cmdText.Append("AgentLogin ON AgentDetail.AgentNumID = AgentLogin.AgentNumID ");

return dt;
}
```